# spaces of probability measures on a Polish space and the convergence

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability

I want to read the topic "spaces of probability measures on a Polish space and the convergence". What is the best reference for that ?

Comment: see the two references cited in http://math.stackexchange.com/q/607924/25917

Comment: billingsley and kurtz-ethier are the standard references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the "canonical" references mentioned above, the book ["A Basic Course in Probability Theory"](http://books.google.com/books?id=clQQVdUNBmcC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Bhattacharya and Waymire has a very nice treatment of this topic in Chapter 5.

Answer (score 2):

Converting Ofer Zeitouni's comment to an answer:

- Billingsley, Patrick.  *Convergence of Probability Measures*.
- Ethier, Stewart and Kurtz, Thomas.  *Markov Processes: Characterization and Convergence*.